# Android Scalable Button Font

Tags: android, xml, button, fonts, size

I would like to have a Button of dimensions e.g. height = 200sp, width = 200sp, but able to scale it's font depending on how long the text it has. I don't want to change it's dimensions or break the word into 2 lines. How can I achieve this?

PS I've seen lot's of examples with TextView, but they don't work for Buttons :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds pretty simple. Consider this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="your-width-in-dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World My Friends!"
        android:maxLines="1"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        app:autoSizeMinTextSize="2sp"
        app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
        app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is a comparison sample, left is 100dp, right is 200dp:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! :-D I tried to use this part:  
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        app:autoSizeMinTextSize="2sp"
        app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
        app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp", but it didn't work, so I think the tag: android:maxLines="1" did the job! Thank you once again! :-)